# mail.php file is not found in pear folder on my cpanel

Tags: php, pear

> Warning: require_once(.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/nameofsite/public_html/contact.php on line 137

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/nameofsite/public_html/contact.php on line 137

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to WHM you'll likely need to install the mail and net_smtp modules via: Home > Software > Module Installers > PHP Extensions and Applications if you don't have access you'll need to request this from your host